# How to calculate Pearson's Correlation for two N-dimensional xarrays?

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray, pearson-correlation

I have two netcdf files, imported as xarrays (please see summary images below), containing seasonal precipitation data (lat, lon, season, precip) over Africa (regridded to the same grid). I would like to compare each season by calculating a Pearson's correlation coefficient (a pattern correlation) to be used in a Taylor diagram (for each season). I have tried numpy's `corrcoef`, but this returns a matrix and I need a single value. I have also tried scipy's `pearsonsr` but it raises an error (The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()).
I am new to python and netcdf files and so would appreciate any guidance.

File1:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'pre' (season: 4, lat: 162, lon: 162)>
array([[[       nan,        nan,        nan, ...,        nan,
                nan,        nan],
        [       nan,        nan,        nan, ...,        nan,
                nan,        nan],
        [       nan,        nan,        nan, ...,        nan,
                nan,        nan],
        ...,
        [       nan,        nan,        nan, ..., 21.462164 ,
         21.921623 , 20.583786 ],
        [       nan,        nan,        nan, ..., 22.240545 ,
         21.24054  , 21.135136 ],
        [       nan,        nan,        nan, ..., 20.78919  ,
         20.45946  , 18.62973  ]]], dtype=float32)
Coordinates:
  * lon   (lon) float64 -20.25 -19.75 -19.25 -18.75 ... 59.25 59.75 60.25
  * lat   (lat) float64 -40.25 -39.75 -39.25 -38.75 ... 39.25 39.75 40.25
  * season(season) object 'DJF' 'JJA' 'MAM' 'SON'
```

File2:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'tp' (season: 4, lat: 162, lon: 162)>
array([[[        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,         nan,
                 nan,         nan],
        [        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,         nan,
                 nan,         nan],
        [        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,         nan,
                 nan,         nan],
        ...,
        [        nan,         nan,         nan, ..., 21.7096725 ,
         21.09724263, 19.69123712],
        [        nan,         nan,         nan, ..., 21.2375123 ,
         20.71120389, 20.73519617],
        [        nan,         nan,         nan, ..., 20.80748653,
         19.70237051, 18.9941896 ]]])
Coordinates:
  * lon   (lon) float64 -20.25 -19.75 -19.25 -18.75 ... 59.25 59.75 60.25
  * lat   (lat) float64 -40.25 -39.75 -39.25 -38.75 ... 39.25 39.75 40.25
  * season(season) object 'DJF' 'JJA' 'MAM' 'SON'
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! When asking a question, it's appreciated if you can please [post formatted text for code and data instead of pictures](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question), as images aren't searchable, are hard for us to copy-paste from, and they aren't friendly for screen readers for those with visual impairments.

Comment: I have formatted as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for a single correlation coefficient across all the values, between one array and the other, try flattening the arrays and then get one of the values off the diagonal (e.g. `[0, 1]`).:

```py
>>> res = np. corrcoef(arr1.values.flat, arr2.values.flat)
>>> res
array([[1.       , 0.9985713],
       [0.9985713, 1.       ]])

>>> res[0, 1]
0.9985713
```

[`corrcoef`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html) always returns an array giving the correlation with respect to each slice of the arrays, but if you're looking for the correlation across all elements in the two then you need to reshape them to be vectors.

Comment: would you say that your solution above is the same as calculating a pattern correlation ("Pearson product-moment coefficient of linear correlation between two variables that are respectively the values of the same variables at corresponding locations on two different maps")? I.e. is the correlation being calculating between corresponding values (in time and space) when flattened?

Comment: Not totally sure. If you're looking for a single correlation coefficient summarizing the behavior of all points in space and time I think that's what you're looking for, but if you're unsure about the appropriate statistical technique you might try asking on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com), a stack exchange network site focused on statistics.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
    pearson = xr.corr(file1,file2)
pearson = np.array(pearson)  #like this you can see the value
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).